# In "R: Python: Html (self-contained) of notebook" what can reasonably be expected to be the intended meaning by the sender

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reticulate

Doing a project at university some of the details of how to hand it in are unclear as I am unfamiliar with language about "mixing" R and Pyhton, and have just recently begun to get acquainted with Python.

The sentence in the headline of the question is about how to hand in the project.

The first sentence reads: "Python: PDF of notebook + original ipynb (zipped)"
The second line, the one in question reads: "R : Python: Html (self-contained) of notebook + original rmd (zipped)".

My guess would be that the sender refers to using python coding in r ( using the reticulate package), then printing the rmarkdown document in html, to be handed in together with the rmd file.

The question is: Does the above interpretation seem resonable or is there a more likely interpretation of what sender intended it to mean?

Comment: I would interpret the `R` comments exactly in that way, in reference to [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/eng-python.html) description of using python in rmd.